# Importing data into Neo4J from CSV

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import a CSV containing nodes (+200000) and edges between them, into Neo4J.

1) For some reason that I could not find out, when the file size is over 5000 lines (or so), relationships do not get created at all.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///export_conceptos_50000.txt" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (c:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto1_sin, cat: csvLine.c1cat})
MERGE (d:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto2_sin, cat: csvLine.c2cat})
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN csvLine.relacion='Is_a' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |     MERGE (c)-[:Is_a]->(d) )
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN csvLine.relacion='Finding_site' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |     MERGE (c)-[:Finding_site]->(d) )
```

So *this* is the original issue: edges are not created.

2) As an alternative, I tried to split the file into smaller ones, and then import via neo4j-shell (Neo4J Linux shell utility).

This is the command line:

```
./neo4j-shell -file /usr/share/neo4j/scripts/query.cypher -path /usr/share/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.1.1/data/databases/graph.db
```

and this is the output:

```
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /usr/share/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.1.1/data/databases/graph.db
```

which I guess is due to the fact that there is already a Neo4J engine running.

Then, how should I specify the target database at the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you might want to do multi-pass, as otherwise you might get problems with eager loading of your CSV data
2. perhaps there is something wrong in your conditionals, if you do multi-pass anyway you can also change them to a simple WHERE

like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///export_conceptos_50000.txt" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (c:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto1_sin, cat: csvLine.c1cat});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///export_conceptos_50000.txt" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (d:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto2_sin, cat: csvLine.c2cat});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///export_conceptos_50000.txt" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
WITH csvLine WHERE csvLine.relacion='Is_a'
MATCH (c:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto1_sin, cat: csvLine.c1cat})
MATCH (d:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto2_sin, cat: csvLine.c2cat})
MERGE (c)-[:Is_a]->(d);


USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///export_conceptos_50000.txt" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
WITH csvLine WHERE csvLine.relacion='Finding_site'
MATCH (c:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto1_sin, cat: csvLine.c1cat})
MATCH (d:Concepto {nom: csvLine.concepto2_sin, cat: csvLine.c2cat})
MERGE (c)-[:Finding_site]->(d);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I took your tip, its been running for a while. Let's see!