# neo4j-shell example of running a Cypher script

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-shell

I need to run a Cypher query against a Neo4J database, from a command line (for batch scheduling purposes).

When I run this:

```
./neo4j-shell -file /usr/share/neo4j/scripts/query.cypher -path /usr/share/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.1.1/data/databases/graph.db
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /usr/share/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.1.1/data/databases/graph.db
```

There is a running Neo4J instance on that database (localhost:7474). I need the script to perform queries against it.

NOTE: this is a split of the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965987/importing-data-into-neo4j-from-csv/41969646#41969646), for the sake of tidiness.

Comment: does the script runs as the same user running the neo4j database ?

Comment: Yes, it is using the default user. Is this a problem?

Comment: I think there's no need to specify the path in this case

Comment: I am having this exact same error. I am wondering if I am just not waiting long enough for the database server to initialize? I am going to try starting Neo4j with `sudo` and try strating the shell with `sudo` to see if anything changes. Are you using the most recent stable version 3.1.1?
Also, I am not using `-file`, I am trying to get into an active shell.
EDIT: Using the `-v` flag, I get: Connection refused to host: localhost.
I imagine something in the confiugration needs to be updated before using the shell. Will report back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

To execute (one or more) Cypher statements from a file while the neo4j server is running, you can use the APOC procedure [apoc.cypher.runFile(*file or url*)](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cypher_execution_2).

Since you mention "batch scheduling", the [Job management and periodic execution](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_job_management_and_periodic_execution) APOC procedures may be helpful. Those procedures could, in turn, execute calls to `apoc.cypher.runFile`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I just spun up a fresh instance of Neo4j-community-3.1.1 today and ran into the exact same problem. Note that I had already created a database using the bulk import tool, so one might need to make a directory for a database (`mkdir data/databases/graph.db`) before using a shell.

I believe your problem might be that you have an instance of Neo4j process running against the database you are trying to access.

For me, shutting down Neo4j, and then starting the shell with an explicit path worked:

```
cd /path/to/neo4j-community-3.1.1/
bin/neo4j stop ## assuming it is already running (may need a port specifier)
bin/neo4j-shell -path data/databases/graph.db
```

For some reason I thought you could have both the shell and the server running, but apparently that is not the case. Hopefully someone will correct me if I am wrong.